# How do I format a double to a string and only show decimal digits when necessary?

Tags: c#, numbers, format, decimal, string-formatting

I have code like:

```
lblFranshizShowInvwNoskhehEdit.Text = string.Format("{0:n}",
    (double)(int.Parse(drDarman["FranshizDarsad"].ToString()) * 
        Convert.ToInt64(RadNumerictxtPayInvwNoskhehEdit.Text)) / 100);
```

But `{0:n0}` string format forces the label's text to not have decimal digits and `{0:n}` string format forces the label's text to have 2 decimal digits (default).

In my scenario I just want decimal digits when necessary / without rounding them / how can I do that?

Comment: Please don't put things like "asp.net / c#" in the title - just use the tags for that. Besides, this has nothing to do with ASP.NET except that you happen to be placing the string you get into the `Text` property of a `Label` control.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just do:

```
string.Format("{0}", yourDouble);
```

It will include only digits when necessary.

If you want other examples of formatting doubles to string check out this [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/).

**EDIT:** Based on your comment you want the `,` seperator so you could do:

```
string.Format("{0:0,0.########}", yourDouble);
```

Just put as many `#` for the max number of decimal places you want to show.  It will only show the digits when necessary but up to the maximum digits based on how many `#` you include in the format.  The `#` means only show a digit if necessary so if you give a number like `123` with no decimal, it will display as `1,234` but if you give it `1234.456`, it will display as `1,234.456`.  If you go beyond the max digits you specified they will be rounded.

**EDIT:** To fix your double zero scenario just change it to:

```
string.Format("{0:#,0.########}", yourDouble);
```

That should work perfectly now :)

Comment: but in this case i will lose thousand separator !

how can i solve this?

Comment: really really appreciate for your edit//
i really apologize / but in this new code 0.4 is like 00.4...
how fix this ?

Comment: @LostLord updated my answer to address that issue.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is mine :

```
string.Format("{0:n2}", double);
```