# c# How do I format a double to a string and only show decimal digits when necessary?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I found this question in StackOverFlow but it didn't solve my problem.
[How do I format a double to a string and only show decimal digits when necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243440/how-do-i-format-a-double-to-a-string-and-only-show-decimal-digits-when-necessary)

```
Weight

0.500
18.000
430.000
```

by the solution in above url my result show in this form:

```
Weight

0.5 
18
430
```

and my problem is in decimal digits, I want show decimal digits in 3 digit,like this:

```
Weight

0.500   
18
430
```

Comment: at a guess, instead of the `#`es, you need to use `000`

Comment: it doesn't work.show many 0 after digits

Comment: So you want three decimal places when when not three zeros. Other wise you want no decimal places?

Comment: I ask because 10.00001 had decimal data but if shown to 3dp will be 10.000 is this how you want? Or would you want that as 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't do what you want with single string.Format(). So you can use a clause:

```
if(weight % 1.0 > 0){
     string.Format("{0:0.000}", weight)
}
else {
     string.Format("{0:0}", weight)
}
```

Or even better:

```
string.Format(weight % 1.0 > 0 ? "{0:0.000}" : "{0:0}", weight)
```

**EDIT:** Sorry missed a bit =))

**EDIT:** If you need to floor result you can use:

```
string.Format(weight % 1.0 >= 0.001 ? "{0:0.000}" : "{0:0}", weight)
```

Comment: Does this work for 0.0001 because that would display was 0.000 when displayed to 3dp

Comment: thanks for your reply , it doesn't work too :(    it show 1 instead of 0.500

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Digit placeholder** `#` with **Zero placeholder** `0` after dot `.` in string format.

```
string num = d % 1 == 0 ? d.ToString(".###") : d.ToString(".000");
```

[Digit placeholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Replaces the pound sign with the corresponding digit if one is
>   present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

[Zero placeholder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> places the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present;
>   otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

This msdn article [Custom Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Strings explains how the number could be formated.

Comment: It add .000 to all values.I want just add .000 to its have decimal digits

Comment: You probably need this, d.ToString(".#00");

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 num.ToString("G3") // for 3 significant digits
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below method:

Usage:

```
    string format1 = GetFormat(123.4567);
    string format2 = GetFormat(123.45);
    string format3 = GetFormat(123.0);
    //format1 = 123.46
    //format2 = 123.45
    //format3 = 123

    private static string GetFormat(double d)
    {            
        string format;
        if (d == Convert.ToInt32(d))
            format = string.Format("{0:0.##}", d);
        else
            format = string.Format("{0:0.00}", d);

        return format;
    }
```

For more information:

http://csharpexamples.com/c-string-formatting-for-double/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
string[] strList = Weight.ToString().Split('.');//or ',' for diffrent regions
if(strList[1] == "000")
     str = string.Format("{0:#,0.########}", b);
```

thank you:)